# Is everyone who receives a paycheck a Shudra?

Tags: shudra

https://www.quora.com/Do-Shudras-think-they-were-born-from-the-feet-of-Brahma/answer/Rami-Sivan

This answer on Quora.com claims:

> So we Sudras are the most blessed and fortunate of all sectors of society because we are the wage earners who maintain society and support all the others. (**BTW - if you receive a pay-check you are a Sudra as well!**)

Is the claim made in the last line true?

Comment: Varna of an individual is always based on birth and the fact that whether he has undergone upnayan sanskar and mantains the vidhi-nishedha as mantained by shastra or not. The fact that a person recieves salary does not make him a shudra.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it is best not to believe anything you read on Quora.

Answer (score 6):

The claim is not true because as per Hindu scriptures even the Vaishyas are qualified to receive wages.

> 36 If someone finds lost property whose owner is unknown, he should
> disclose it to the king. 37 The king should have it publicized and
> keep it safely for a year, 38 after which time a quarter goes to the
> finder and the rest to the king. 39 Ownership is established by
> inheritance, purchase, partition, possession, and discovery; 40
> additionally, acceptance for Brahmins, 41 conquest for Ksatriyas, 42
> **and wages for Vaisyas and ´Sudras. 43**
>
> **Gautama Dharma Sutras 10.36-10.43**

Also in times of distress, anyone (belonging to any of the four castes) can do work for wages as per Manu. But only in times of distress not otherwise.

> Manu smriti 10.115. There are seven lawful modes of acquiring
> property, (viz.) inheritance, finding or friendly donation, purchase,
> conquest, lending at interest, the performance of work, and the
> acceptance of gifts from virtuous men.
>
> 10.116. Learning, mechanical arts, **work for wages**, service, rearing cattle, traffic, agriculture, contentment (with little), alms,
> and receiving interest on money, **are the ten modes of subsistence
> (permitted to all men in times of distress).**

Answer (score 2):

From the standpoint of Nahusha Prashna , Vana Parva Mahabharata

> दानं क्षमा शीलम आनृशंस्यं दमॊ घृणा
> दृश्यन्ते यत्र नागेन्द्र स बराह्मण इति समृतः
> satyaṃ dānaṃ kṣamā śīlam ānṛśaṃsyaṃ damo ghṛṇā
> dṛśyante yatra nāgendra sa brāhmaṇa iti smṛtaḥ
>
> Truthfulness, generosity, patience, good character, compassion, self-control, tenderness One in whom these are seen, O King of Snakes, he is a Brahmana. Thus it is known.

> शूद्रे चैतद भवेल लक्ष्यं दविजे तच च न विद्यते
> śūdre caitad bhavel lakṣyaṃ dvije tac    ca na vidyate
>
> Nahusha rightly counters Yudhishtra that qualities of Truthfulness, generosity, non-anger, compassion, nonviolence, and tenderness are found even in Shudras so how can it be an identifying trait of a Brahmana.

> न वै शूद्रॊ भवेच छूद्रॊ बराह्मणॊ न च बराह्मणः
> na vai śūdro bhavec chūdro
> brāhmaṇo   na ca brāhmaṇaḥ
>
> A shudra in whom these virtues exist and a dvija in whom they do not exist, that shudra is not a shudra and that Brahmana is not a Brahmana.(reply by Yudhishtira)

> यत्रैतल लक्ष्यते सर्पवृत्तं स बराह्मणः समृतः
> यत्रैतन न भवेत सर्पतं शूद्रम इति निर्दिशेत
> yatraital lakṣyate sarpavṛttaṃ sa brāhmaṇaḥ smṛtaḥ
> yatraitan na bhavet sarpataṃ śūdram iti nirdiśet
>
> O Snake, in whom these virtues exist, he is a Brahmana, it is said. O snake, in whom these virtues do not exist, he is a shudra. Thus it is taught.

Yudhishtra clarifies beyond a shadow of doubt that the presence of virtuous characters alone qualifies a person as a Brahmana and the lack of it brings down to a default state, Shudra.

(Translation Courtesy : Satchitananda)

(In some prev. QA thread of this stack exchange , one can locate the reference from Skanda Purana , which ascertains that the default state is shudra.)

Srimad Bhagavad Mahapuran 11.17.42

> brahmanasya hi deho ’yam
>  ksudra-kamaya nesyate
> krcchraya tapase ceha
>  pretyananta-sukhaya ca
>
> The body of a brahmana is not intended to enjoy insignificant material sense gratification; rather, by accepting difficult austerities in his life, a brahmana will enjoy unlimited happiness after death.

(The opposite of which applies to shudra)

Bhagavad Gita 4.13

> chātur-varṇyaṁ mayā sṛiṣhṭaṁ guṇa-karma-vibhāgaśhaḥ
> tasya kartāram api māṁ viddhyakartāram avyayam
>
> The four categories of occupations were created by Me according to people’s qualities and activities. Although I am the Creator of this system, know Me to be the Non-doer and Eternal.
> English Translation by Swami Mukundananda )

(The 6 combinations generated out of gunaas(sattva,rajas,tamas) and thier quotient(primary ,secondary , tertiary) is fitted in the 4 categories of Varna , in which (tamas, primary )is regarded as shudra..and all the 4 Varanas are required for sustenance.. Lord does create , but not anything new, clarified as a part of satkaryavada, ..Avirodha Adhyaya brahmasutra.in philosophy)

Bhagavad Gita 18.41

> brāhmaṇa-kṣhatriya-viśhāṁ śhūdrāṇāṁ cha parantapa
> karmāṇi pravibhaktāni svabhāva-prabhavair guṇaiḥ
>
> The duties of the Brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas, and Shudras—are distributed according to their qualities, in accordance with their guṇas (and not by birth).English Translation by Swami Mukundananda )

(Here svabhava prabhavair gunaihi.. implies one would be impelled to act in concordance with one's own gunaas,  ..inenvitable on one's own accord. So Varna is not about any external enforcement, but an internal tendency)

Bhagavad Gita 18.44

> kṛiṣhi-gau-rakṣhya-vāṇijyaṁ vaiśhya-karma svabhāva-jam
> paricharyātmakaṁ karma śhūdrasyāpi svabhāva-jam
>
> Agriculture, dairy farming, and commerce are the natural works for those with the qualities of Vaishyas. Serving through work is the natural duty for those with the qualities of Shudras.
> English Translation by Swami Mukundananda )

Reg.  the (reference) from where the 'receipt of a paychek' is connoted, why should the author not be asked, who stated it?

Footnote:
sattva , rajas and tamas aren't deterministic constituents, and may be impacted in accordance to an individuals conditioning. so how can anyone comment on an individual's Varna(except for Lord, seers..)

Hence it is sociologically feasible to
fix varna by birth only...for the welfare of common good(Lokasangraha), though the scriptures are beyond sociological constraints.

Comment: Do you believe Vidura had brahminical qualities ? Do you believe Brahmins duty is to undergo upanayana and perform vedic rituals ? If so, why did Vidura not wear sacred thread and do yagnas ?

Comment: Vidhura does perform an yajna known as Adhithi Yajna( one of Pancha Yajna) and the Yajneshwara is Lord Krishna.Had there been a yajna that ever existed ,or will ever exist , superior to this yajna!

Comment: sattva , rajas and tamas aren't deterministic constituents, and may be impacted in accordance to an individuals conditioning. so how can anyone comment on an individual's Varna(except for Lord, seers..)

Hence it is sociologically feasible to fix varna by birth only...for the welfare of common good(Lokasangraha), though the scriptures are beyond sociological constraints

Comment: > Adhithi Yajna.

this is not exclusive to dwijas. anyone can serve guests. we're talking about rituals only brahmins can perform.

Comment: > so how can anyone comment on an individual's Varna. anyone can't, but scriptures can. Gruhya sutras state "perform upanayana for brahmin at age 7". how does one know if a kid is brahmin or shudra ? you can't use your common sense, because it can be subjective. you have to follow birth/varna rules - if parents brahmin, so is child. but birth is not sufficient, he has to undergo samskaras, and also have character.

Comment: quite true. Any speculation on varna is subjective and implausible

Comment: exactly that's why it has to be determined by birth. Because we trust that Bhagavan is a better determiner of varna than us humans. and Bhagavan decides your birth based on your karma according to perfect justice.