# Is working for wage sin for twice-born castes?

Tags: caste-system, varna

Is working for wage sin for twice born castes (Brahmin , Kshatriya and Vaishayas) ? Does it lead them to hell ?

Comment: Related - [Is everyone who receives a paycheck a Shudra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/51070/23709)